# smtp exception Failed Recipient

Tags: c#, .net, exception, smtpclient

I have the following code in my application:

```
catch (SmtpException oSMTPException)
{
    string sFailedEmailIds = string.Empty;
    string[] sMailids = null;

    ((System.Net.Mail.SmtpFailedRecipientsException)(oSMTPException)).
        InnerExceptions[0].FailedRecipient
}
```

I have a number of mail IDs to which the mail has not been sent.
I want to store the details in a string `sFailedEmailIds`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

I don't exactly know what you want to store, but I guess you want all the email IDs, so this is something similar I recently did:

```
catch (SmtpFailedRecipientsException e)
{
    string sFailedEmailIds = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < e.InnerExceptions.Length; i++)
    {
        SmtpStatusCode status = e.InnerExceptions[i].StatusCode;
        if (status == SmtpStatusCode.MailboxBusy ||
            status == SmtpStatusCode.MailboxUnavailable) {
            sFailedEmailIds += e.InnerExceptions[i].FailedRecipient.Split('<', '>')[1] + ", ";
        } else {
            // other statuscode that you want to handle
        }
    }

    return sFailedEmailIds;
}
```

I use the SmtpFailedRecipientsException instead of SmtpException because it has all the emails that failed.

Hope it helps. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
string sFailedEmailIds = String.Join(",", ((System.Net.Mail.SmtpFailedRecipientsException)(oSMTPException)).InnerExceptions.Select(x=>x.FailedRecipient));
```

Comment: Gives me the following two errors <br> The best overloaded method match for 'string.Join(string, string[])' has some invalid arguments <br> Argument '2' cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'string[]'